# Bios always jumps on first sector (512B) why ? is this some kind of BIOS limitation?

Tags: linux, boot, bios, bootstrapping, uefi

First I am not the expert in Booting but would like to understand it better way.

1) System boots goes to BIOS and BIOS goes to first boot sector which is first 512 bytes and from there it reads the first 440 bytes. This is called as bootloader or boot strap, this code in turn does everything for us, it jumps (for next stages), reads partition table, follows fdisk signature (boot flag) if necessary etc.  I have very basic question in mind. May be it will be a dumb question :(

2) why BIOS can read only first sector (512 Bytes), because of this tiny space boot loaders cant fit there, they have to jump stage to stage. Why cant BIOS read more than 512 bytes ?  For time being say BIOS is able to read first 100MB. 100MB is more than enough to fit boot loader there, no need to jump, we can write nice full featured boot loaders for it which can give nice GUI to end user. (UEFI is exactly dong the same by creating separate partition)

3) Why only 512Bytes ? why BIOS cant go beyond that ?

4) I hear BIOS is designed for 8-bit processors something like (maybe I am completely wrong). Can you please explain me this ?

Sorry for the long description but I am new to stackoverflow. I wanted to add nice disk layout diagram but it says I should have atleast 10 reputations. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Historical reasons". As pointed out, newer approaches have supplanted the need to increase the space.

Comment: What historical reasons ? I really need to understand this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This boot method had to work on the original 1982 IBM PC, which came standard with 16KB of RAM. This 16KB holds BIOS data, OS (MS-DOS), apps, and everything. With so little RAM, engineers had to use it conservatively.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for the response, I heard it was desgined for IBM-PC 5150 which used use intel 8088 which was 16-bit processor and it used to access upto 1 MB of RAM. So I can understand there was a big memory limitation but still why BIOS go beyond 512 Bytes. Why cant BIOS address more than 512 Bytes of space. Is this RAM limitation restricting BIOS from going beyond 512 Bytes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When PC's first came on the scene they had no more than 640k ram, and those were the deluxe models.

The first IBM XT (Affectionately named 'The Tank' because it was light military green and had a solid steel case) only had an 8k BIOS chip, with 512k (Half a megabyte) becoming the standard  when the compatible wars started.

With these first PC's there was no concept of the hard disk, hard disks where large multi platter things that looked like a cake shelf with a glass cover over (Like you might see in a coffee shop) and were usually so heavy that they took 2 or 3 people to lift them.

Often these large platter cases where only ever connected to mainframes at the time, and where way too large to even consider being provided for a desktop PC, so the floppy disk was used instead.

The first ever round of these floppy disks could hold no more than approx 300k and were 5.25 inches square by about 2.5 millimeters thick, some were double sided, so could hold 600k.  There was also a range of different types of software and disk encoder chips that could read/write different densities, but the bottom line was space on them was very, very limited.

Couple that with the fact, that most BIOSes at the time where only around about 16k to 32k in size, you had to fit as much as possible to get the machine up and running , and in the case of the IBM fit a rom based basic interpreter in there too so that with no external operating system, the computer was still usable for general computing tasks.

All of these restrictions meant that smaller was better.

Rather than have a flattened disk size with a large monolithic loader on, it was better to 'format' these floppy disks so that most of the space was user space, and allowed the end user to effectively customize the boot software (EG: remove parts of the OS they didn't use) so the initial loader that kick started everything was restricted to the first 512 bytes of the disk.

The other main reason was the sheer verity of different disk systems that were available back then (Remember this was way before the industry was standardized) so putting something right at the beginning of the disk was guaranteed to be found no matter how weirdly the running OS set the rest of the disk up for it's own use, because no seeking was involved, you didn't have to look at format marks and attempt to understand some weird directory format.  You simply moved the drive head to it's rest position, then read 512 bytes, simple as that.

Once phoenix produced the first clone of the IBM Bios, and won over IBM in court when the company tried to sue them for theft of intellectual property, the flood gates opened.  Almost overnight, everyone started to make BIOS systems, and the PC market as we know to day exploded into a mess of standards in interfaces of all different types.

Pretty soon, the vendor lock-in started, so the IEE/ANSI/ISO and other standards bodies started to lay down the law, by making a specification on how EVERYONE had to remain compatible with everyone else, those standards have held true right through too today's modern era of computing.

By the time we got massive hard drives on the scene and bootable CD's, USB's and all manner of other things, these standards (of which the 512b boot sector was part) where SO DEEPLY entrenched in the grander scheme of things, that it was impossible to change them.

Only a few brave companies dared venture into that territory and had limited success, Sun Micro Systems for example were one of the brave few.  If you look at a Sun Raq3 (You can pick them up on Ebay for next to nothing) they have a boot loader that mimics exactly what the PC disk based loader does, but it boots out of rom until the second stage , where up on it immediately looks for a /boot partition on a standard Linux based disk layout, thus even though disks in these machines still have the standard 512 byte boot block, it's actually not used.

Hope that gives you the insight you want, given that I lived through a lot of it I can remember a lot of it too including the machines that didn't use the 512 byte boot block.

Comment: "there was no concept of the hard disk" is not true. Full-height 5.25" hard drives were definitely available in the PC and XT era, although being expensive they were optional equipment rather than standard until prices came down.

Comment: Granted, but they weren't available to the general public, and everyone I knew at the time except for the hardcore engineers that where actually using this 'new' stuff, no one had any clue.  To the average consumer that is (or was) a true statement.

Comment: The [ST-506](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ST-506) was a 5MB 5.25" hard drive introduced in 1980 and was available to the general public on the open market, albeit at a very high price. It is not accurate to say that the only hard drives of the PC / XT era were cake-box sized things.

Comment: I'm not disputing that, what I'm saying is that to the general public (Even though the drive was released) it wasn't common knowledge that it was available, MOST people still used floppy's, therefore I believe my comment still stands.

Comment: Given the high price, the general public didn't even consider the 'exotic' hard drive as an option. Quibbling over whether it was in the manufacturers catalogue is churlish and qualifies for the 'Bronism' of choice.

Comment: Not in the compatibles they didn't, 512k was already the standard by the time Compaq came on the market. and as for the 32/64k 'Actually' your still wrong, because the first ever production BIOS for the first ever XT release only included a basic loader and ROM-Basic in an 8k chip.